# Assigning a certain amount of CPU power to a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, time

I use the time command in a script to calculate the runtime.

But sometimes

```
gzip -4 file
```

is done in less time than

```
gzip -1 file
```

Why is this happening؟

How can I make the CPU power level the same at all times running the script?

Could this happen because of the low file size?

note: I use Translator.

**Both files are the same.**

Comment: Which times -- wall time, sys time, user time?  After the first run on a file, the file is in memory, so will be more quickly accessed if another command is run on it.package schedtool gives cpu affinity controls, there are others.

Comment: sudo nice -n 5 "gzip -4 file"

Comment: Which times? Sometimes all three. How do I make the cpu consumption of the commands the same?